# Unto: an unusual usage

Tags: prepositions, archaicisms

In the King James version, Luke 23:15 says

> No, nor yet Herod: for I sent you to him; and, lo, nothing worthy of death is done **unto** him.

It is clear from the context that Pilate is here telling Christ's accusers that Herod found no reason to put Jesus to death. So this may be understood to say

> No, nor yet Herod: for I sent you to him; and, lo, nothing worthy of death is done **by** him.

Is there an archaic definition of "unto" that equates it to "by?"

Comment: Not so unusual for Early Modern English. It just means *to*.

Comment: If you want an explanation of wording in the KJV you should probably go to http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 1):

Here is some additional context for the quoted passage (from the [Adam Clarke edition of the King James version of the Bible](https://books.google.com/books?id=GeY8AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA468&dq=%22nothing+worthy+of+death+is+done+unto+him%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAWoVChMI0M_NlOz2xgIVSyyICh2pQAtS#v=onepage&q=%22nothing%20worthy%20of%20death%20is%20done%20unto%20him%22&f=false) [1825]):

> **13** And Pilate, when he had called together the chief priests and the rulers and the people,
>
> **14** Said unto them, Ye have brought this man unto me, as one that perverteth the people : and behold, I, having examined him before you, have found no fault in this man, touching those things whereof ye accuse him :
>
> **15** No, nor yet Herod : for I sent you to him ; and lo, nothing worthy of death is done unto him.

A straightforward reading of the passage might conclude that Pontius Pilate is saying that Jesus did nothing to Herod—either personally or in terms of Herod's role as the personification of the state of Judea—that would justify a death sentence against Jesus. The *unto* at "done unto him" would thus be equivalent to *to*, just as the *unto* in verse 14 at "Said unto them" is.

In this interpretation, the *you* at "sent you to him" would seem refer to "the chief priests and the rulers and the people," which makes for a rather crowded room at Herod's hall of justice.

Adam Clarke, however, reads verse 15 somewhat differently, though it isn't clear to me who Clarke thinks the *you* and the *him* in the phrase "I sent you to him" are. Here is his footnote on this verse:

> *Nothing worthy of death is done unto him*] Or rather, *nothing worthy of death is committed by him*, Πεπζαγμενον αυτω, not, *done unto him*. This phrase is of the same sense with ουδεν πεπζαχεν αυτος, *he hath done nothing*, and is frequent in the purest Attic [Greek] writers.

Evidently, Clarke agrees with the OP that *unto* is to be understood in a rather unusual way in the phrase "nothing worthy of death is done unto him."

Answer (score 1):

The last meaning (of 28!) that the *OED* gives unto "unto" is that of attributing the meaning of an *adjective* to a noun.  The examples given include "*dangerous* **unto** England" and "*cruel* **unto** ... Troy."  I think the simplest interpretation is

> nothing *death-worthy* **unto** him is done

This leaves "is done" slightly ambiguous.  It could mean that Jesus has done nothing that makes him worthy of execution, or it could mean that his accusers have accomplished nothing to show that he is.

Disclaimer:  I have merely examined a dictionary.  I am an expert in neither the koine nor New Testament exegesis.  So there.